# Run delta-import and full-import in solr parallerly

Tags: solr, import, dih

I have dih core. Where, there are two entities one does a delta-import via full-import and other does delta-import to handle deletes.

I'm using delta-import via full-import because only delta-import is taking [longer time than full-import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45540956/efficiency-aspect-of-delta-import-in-solr).

Now, I'm applying a cron job so, that the imports are automated. In this case, is it possible to run both the imports simultaneously. Such that one takes care of updates and the other takes care of deletes.

Is it possible to run delta-import and full-import simultaneously at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not if you have a single endpoint...but you can perfectly do this:

1. duplicate your DIH configuration (in solrconfig.xml add a second /dataimport2, that points to db-data-config2.xml
2. put one of the entities in one, and the other in the other

Now you can call them both simultaneously

Comment: So, is it possible to have multiple data import request handlers in solrconfig.xml file?